# Importing all files from a leading js file to easy import for all components

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

In React Components importing files become torturing like that..

in one page "../../component another page ../component anotherpage @/ALLCOMPONENTS/compoent  etc.. always trying to find main way of component etc...

so I prepare a js file named allExports.js  and importing all components , functions, css files , image to there and than importing files from there easly...

allExports.js is like that :

```
 // function example 

     export { getMyList } from 'scripts/Inducer'; // async function
     export { openBox   } from 'scripts/Inducer'; // Normal Function
 
// CSS example

    export { default as mainHeadersCss } from 'mainHeaders.module.scss';

// image example

    export { default as myLogoShadowed }         from 'public/logos/logo.png';

// component example

    const SubModalBox        = lazy(() => import( 'components/9SUBMODAL'));
```

and also example of a component  like below :

```
import { getMyList,openBox ,mainHeadersCss ,myLogoShadowed,SubModalBox }  from 'allExports';
```

In here component lazyload is work good and only the components I call working others are not...

but allothers are always load always starting React and on opening loading whitescreen take time .. but a lot of thing I try to lazyload for function , iömage and css .. I couldnt handle...

THe main logic is wrong? maybe not importing page is good for allexport and maybe is there a way to convert exporting page to a simple rotating page?